# Add delay on actor answer

Tags: scala, akka

Is there a way to add some delay to Akka actor answering? I have a business requirement for one specific actor to provide any response for at least in 1 second.

I guess I can do this with `Thread.sleep(1000L)`, but I'm just not sure it is good practice for async Akka systems since it is thread-blocking. There should be a way to schedule message sending with delay.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be solved by using the [scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html)

```
import system.dispatcher
import scala.concurrent.duration._

system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 second, targetActor, "yourMessage")
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. How to generalise this logic for any possible message not only "yourMessage" string ?

Comment: As far as I remember, the `scheduleOnce` method should accept any arbitrary message that you would normally send via the `!` / `ask`method. Just transform `<actor> ! <message>` to `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 second, <actor>, <message>)`.